# PHP convert one array to different formatted array

Tags: php, mysql

**My query**

```
$sql ="select tTrack from tblcourse where tCourseCode = 'AZURE'";
$rs = mysql_query($sql);
$row_rs_course_category = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs);
```

gives me value `Array ( [tTrack] => MS,CLOUD )`

but i need to conver that array to  this format from PHP

```
Array ( [0] => MS [1] => CLOUD )
```

how do i do it in php

Comment: Try `explode(',', $row_rs_course_category['tTrack']);`

Comment: why dont you just explode the array value and generate a new array..

Comment: Just to make you aware these functions have been deprecated http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php

Comment: [`MySQL`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) (`mysql_*` functions) extension is [***deprecated***](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php). I suggest to use [`MySQLi`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (`mysqli_*` functions) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`explode`](http://php.net/explode) function to get this.

```
$newValue = explode(",", $row_rs_course_category['tTrack']);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `explode()`.

```
$value = explode(',',$row_rs_course_category['tTrack'] );
echo "<pre>";
print_r($value);
//Array ( [0] => MS [1] => CLOUD )
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function to achieve this

```
$array = array ( 'tTrack' => 'MS,CLOUD' );
$array1 = explode(',', $array['tTrack']);
var_dump($array1);
```

this will output

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(2) "MS" [1]=> string(5) "CLOUD" }
```

Answer (score 0):

[explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) can help you

try this

```
$array = explode("," , $row_rs_course_category['tTrack']);
print_r($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **PHP** `explode` function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

```
$newArr = explode(',', $row_rs_course_category['tTrack']);
print_r($newArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

User Php `explode()` function:

Look on Below link :

http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

```
$sql ="select tTrack from tblcourse where tCourseCode = 'AZURE'";
$rs = mysql_query($sql);
$row_rs_course_category = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs);
if(isset($row_rs_course_category['tTrack']) && $row_rs_course_category['tTrack'] != '')
{
  $result = explode(',',$row_rs_course_category['tTrack'] );
  echo "<pre>";
  print_r($value);
 }
```

**array explode ( string $delimiter , string $string [, int $limit ] )**

***delimiter***

The boundary string.

***string***

The input string.

***limit***

If limit is set and positive, the returned array will contain a maximum of limit elements with the last element containing the rest of string.

If the limit parameter is negative, all components except the last -limit are returned.

If the limit parameter is zero, then this is treated as 1.

Answer (score 0):

Switch to sqli, and do what they said explode the array.

```
$your_array=Array ( 'tTrack' => "MS,CLOUD" );
$new_array=explode(",",$your_array['tTrack']);
print_r($new_array);
```